# How can I stop stoppropagation reaching the document

Tags: javascript

If do this:

```
$('body').bind('touchmove',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    });
$('#scrollarea').bind('touchmove',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

Then the body can nolonger be scrolled but, If I am scrolling the #scrollarea stopPropagation re-enables the scrolling of the document...

How can I stop stopPropagation when it bubbles up to the document?

Comment: I don't understand `Bubbles up`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the third paramter of bubbling?

```
$('#scrollarea').bind('touchmove',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```